# tried to install wine

Tags: wine

I read if I wish to run Windows based programs in Ubuntu without the full licence I need to install wine.
Now I typed:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

After reading package list is done at the end the message says

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
   wine : Depends: Wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed 
E: unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages .
```

What can I do?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get install wine1.6`?

Answer (score 2):

in case you have broken package try

```
sudo apt-get install -f 
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

then run wine .

**N.B :** If there is a specific reason to emulate windows applications with administration capabilities or compatibility with older version of windows (95,98,ME...) you should type `WINARCH=32 winecfg` before running wine.

[*Source*](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-users/2005-September/018921.html)